# ASP.NET Data getting mixed up between 2 different users

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have created a web forms application using ASP.NET with C# (.NET 4.7.2) as the code behind. I am using ADO.NET Entity as the connection to a SQL Server 2019 database.

I have created a page with 2 text boxes. Reference number and code. When a user enters Reference number and code into the boxes and click submit the data is stored in the database the page redirects to a detailed page using URL parameters of `details.aspx?ref=xxxxxx&c=xxxxxx`.

The `details.aspx` page then loads. Using the code behind page load section, I retrieve the URL parameters from `Request.QueryString`. Using the results of the query I filter a record set and display some text & image data.

The issue I'm seeing is if 2 users press the submit button at the same time using different data they get a mixture of each others data returned on the next page. If they press it at different times it works fine (we confirmed this using 2 laptops being pressed at the same time by the same person).

Does anyone have any pointers as we have done a lot of searching and at this time and cannot find a solution.

So far we have tried:

- IIS Caching - prevent all caching on user-mode and Kernel mode
- Adding the following to the page load section of each page

  ```
   Response.CacheControl = "private";
   Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  ```
- Cookies are not being used

We have full access to the Web Server/Database

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you must provide the code, a part of the code that makes this - its very difficult to do that, so you have some error for sure, **some "common" static variable**, some wrong session...

Comment: Are you using a static class to persist values (you can't do that). And are you using session() here?

Answer (score 0):

Hi After reading Aristos comment I modified the code and removed static class where I had put global variables. Once I had recoded the page to use local variables all worked as expected.

Thanks for the tip.

I did come across a few post which indicated the same but had not got round to trying that yet.

Many Thanks